# Simple Pub-Sub Event Emitter

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have written a basic event emitter in JavaScript and I'd like some feedback on my design. I tried to make it as simple and minimalist as possible, as I'd like it to be understandable by anyone.

I have wrapped the code itself in a top-level "module" that adds it to the global namespace under the name `events`. I have also attempted to document it to the best of my ability using JSDoc.

**The code**

```javascript
(function(name, root, factory) {

  // If we don't have a root object with the provided name, create one.
  if (typeof(root[name]) !== 'object') {
    root[name] = {};
  }

  // Pass the root object into the factory.
  factory(root[name]);
})('events', this, function(events) {

  /**
   * Returns whether or not the emitter has the provided event and callback.
   *
   * <p>
   * Note that the <code>callback</code> argument is optional and if not
   * provided will cause the method to return just whether the emitter has the
   * provided event.
   * <p>
   *
   * @param {Object} callbacks - The callbacks object to check.
   * @param {string} event - The name of the event to check.
   * @param {Function} [callback] - The callback to check.
   *
   * @returns {Boolean} whether or not the emitter has the provided event and
   *                    callback
   */
  function has(callbacks, event, callback) {
    // If callback was not provided.
    if (callback === undefined) {
      // Check whether the event exists.
      return callbacks[event] instanceof Array;
    } else if (has(callbacks, event)) {
      // Otherwise if the event exists, check if the callback exists.
      return callbacks[event].indexOf(callback) !== -1;
    }

    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Adds a listener for the provided event to the emitter.
   *
   * @param {Object} callbacks - The callbacks object to add the event listener
   *                             to.
   * @param {string} event - The name of the event to listen for.
   * @param {Function} callback - The callback for the event.
   *
   * @return {EventEmitter} the event emitter
   */
  function on(callbacks, event, callback) {
    // If the event exists and the callback does not exist.
    if (has(callbacks, event)) {
      if (!has(callbacks, event, callback)) {
        // Add the callback.
        callbacks[event].push(callback);
      }
    } else {
      // Otherwise, create the array and add the callback to it.
      callbacks[event] = [callback];
    }

    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Removes a listener for the provided event from the emitter.
   *
   * <p>
   * Note that the <code>callback</code> argument is optional and if not
   * provided will cause the method to remove all listeners for the provided
   * event.
   * <p>
   *
   * @param {Object} callbacks - The callbacks object to remove the event
   *                             listener from.
   * @param {string} event - The name of the event to remove.
   * @param {Function} callback - The callback to remove.
   *
   * @return {EventEmitter} The event emitter.
   */
  function off(callbacks, event, callback) {
    // If the event and callback exist.
    if (has(callbacks, event, callback)) {
      // Remove the callback.
      callbacks[event].splice(callbacks[event].indexOf(callback), 1);
    }

    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Emits an event to all event listeners.
   *
   * @param {Object} callbacks - The callbacks object to emit the event on.
   * @param {string} event - The name of the event to emit.
   * @param {...*} arguments - The arguments to forward to the event
   *                             listeners.
   *
   * @return {EventEmitter} The event emitter.
   */
  function emit(callbacks, event) {

    // If the event exists.
    if (has(callbacks, event)) {
      // Get the arguments excluding the callbacks and event arguments.
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
      // Iterate all of the callbacks for the event.
      callbacks[event].forEach(function(callback) {
        // Set a timeout so that any exceptions don't stop the other callbacks
        // from executing.
        setTimeout(function() {
          // Run the callback with the arguments provided.
          callback.apply(null, args);
        }, 0);
      });
    }

    return this;
  }

  /**
   * An event emitter.
   *
   * <p>
   * Note that this class is dynamically created using
   * {@linkcode EventEmitter.mixin}, causing it's methods to not be documented.
   * Take a look at the "see" section and {@linkcode EventEmitter.mixin} below
   * for a list of instance methods.
   * </p>
   *
   * @class
   *
   * @see {@linkcode on}
   * @see {@linkcode off}
   * @see {@linkcode emit}
   */
  function EventEmitter() { }

  /**
   * Turns the provided object into an event emitter.
   *
   * <p>
   * This method copies the {@linkcode on}, {@linkcode off} and
   * {@linkcode emit} methods on to the provided object, effectively turning it
   * into an event emitter.
   * <p>
   *
   * <p>
   * Note that the <code>callback</code> argument is optional and if not
   * provided will cause the method to return a new object with the
   * aforementioned methods. This is the same as calling
   * {@linkcode EventEmitter.mixin EventEmitter.mixin({})}.
   * <p>
   *
   * @param {(Object|Function)} [object] - The object to turn into an event
   *                                       emitter.
   *
   * @return {(Object|Function)} The object passed in.
   *
   * @see {@linkcode on}
   * @see {@linkcode off}
   * @see {@linkcode emit}
   */
  EventEmitter.mixin = function(object) {
    // The object to be returned once the mixin is completed.
    var returnObject = object;

    // If we aren't given an object.
    if (typeof(object) === 'undefined') {
      // Use a default one and change the return object to it.
      object = {};
      returnObject = object;
    } else if (typeof(object) === 'function') {
      // Otherwise if we are given a function, apply the mixin to it's
      // prototype.
      object = object.prototype;
    }

    // The callbacks for the event emitter.
    var callbacks = {};

    // Add the methods to the object.
    object.on = on.bind(object, callbacks);
    object.off = off.bind(object, callbacks);
    object.emit = emit.bind(object, callbacks);

    return returnObject;
  };

  // Make {@link EventEmitter} into a real event emitter.
  EventEmitter.mixin(EventEmitter);

  events.EventEmitter = EventEmitter;
});
```

And some examples of using it:

**Using the `EventEmitter` class**

```javascript
var emitter = new events.EventEmitter();

emitter.on('add_numbers', function(first, second) {
  console.log(first + ' + ' + second + ' = ' + (first + second));
});

emitter.emit('add_numbers', 5, 10);
```

**Turning an existing class into an event emitter**

```javascript
// Creating the class

function Person() {}

Person.prototype.say = function() {
  var emitArguments = Array.prototype.concat.apply(['speak'], arguments);

  this.emit.apply(this, emitArguments);
};

events.EventEmitter.mixin(Person);

// Using the class

var joe = new Person();

joe.on('speak', function() {
  var words = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ' ');

  console.log('Joe said "' + words + '"');
});

joe.say('Hello everyone!', 'My name is Joe.');
```

**Gripes**

One thing I have considered doing is putting the `has`, `on`, `off` and `emit` methods into a `getMethods` function which accepts the `callbacks` object. This would mean I wouldn't "pollute" the function signatures with an argument never seen by anything outside of the events module. Is this something worth doing?

Also, should I expose the `has` method to things outside the events module? I can't really think of a case where it is needed.