# Java Pub Sub implementation using broker

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I have developed a simple pubsub event subscription in java. Something similar to this thread

[Simple Pub-Sub Event Emitter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128505/simple-pub-sub-event-emitter)

These are the goals.

1. Class should be able to "listen" to events happening in the module.
2. It should be disconnected from the event emitter. That is, the listeners shouldn't have to know which classes may be emitting events.
3. All the subscribers should be notified parallelly.

My Broker.java

```
import java.util.*;

public final class  Broker {
    private Object mutex = new Object();
    static class CommonTopics{
        private CommonTopics(){}
        public static final String ON_CACHE_RESET = "onCacheReset";
    }
    private static Broker brokerInstance;
    private Broker(){

    }
    public static Broker getInstance(){
        if(null== brokerInstance){
            brokerInstance = new Broker();
        }
        return brokerInstance;
    }

    private Map<String, Set<Subscriber>> subscribers = new HashMap<>();

    public boolean deregister(String topic, Subscriber subscriber) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            final Set<Subscriber> subs = this.subscribers.get(topic);
            return subs.remove(subscriber);
        }
    }

    public boolean register(String topic, Subscriber subscriber) {
        boolean returnVal;
        synchronized (mutex) {
            if (subscribers.containsKey(topic)) {
                returnVal = subscribers.get(topic).add(subscriber);
            } else {
                Set<Subscriber> sub = new HashSet<>();
                returnVal = sub.add(subscriber);
                subscribers.put(topic, sub);
            }
        }
        return returnVal;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String topic,Map map){
        synchronized (mutex) {
            final Set<Subscriber> sub = this.subscribers.get(topic);
            sub.parallelStream().forEach(subscriber -> subscriber.update(map));
        }
    }

}
```

My Subscriber interface

```
import java.util.Map;

public interface Subscriber {
    public void update(Map map);
}
```

And an example subscriber

```
import java.util.Map;

public class ExampleSubscriber implements Subscriber {
    @Override
    public void update(Map map) {
        System.out.println(map.get("oldCachedValue"));
        System.out.println(map.get("newCachedValue"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExampleSubscriber subscriber = new ExampleSubscriber();
        Broker.getInstance().register(Broker.CommonTopics.ON_CACHE_RESET,subscriber);
    }
}
```

Example event emmitter

```
Map m = new HashMap();
        m.put("oldCachedValue","Yes");
        m.put("newCachedValue","No");
        Broker.getInstance().sendMessage(Broker.CommonTopics.ON_CACHE_RESET,m);
```

Comment: I see a raw type in the method `Subscriber.update(Map)`, namely `Map`, which is probably not a good idea. However, I don't know what the purpose of this `Map` is, so I cannot suggest an alternative. What does this `Map` represent?

Comment: @Stingy mainly just to send any arbitrary data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First of all, `mutex` should be `final`, since you are synchronizing on it. In the current state of your code, it wouldn't make much difference, since it is `private` anyway and never exposed outside the class, but still, if you make it `final`, then the field `mutex` is protected against modification by the compiler, reducing the risk of bugs.
- If you don't ever intend to change `brokerInstance`, i.e. if `Broker` is intended to be a singleton, you can also make `brokerInstance` `final` and initialize it immediately with its declaration. This would eliminate the need for the `if` construct in the method `getInstance()`. After googling about this, I found out that the purpose of what you are doing is probably lazy initialization. However, in [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475602/singleton-public-static-final), some points are made in favor of the approach with the `final` variable (especially the point about thread safety might be interesting to you).
- You might consider taking advantage of the class [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) for your synchronization purposes. A `ConcurrentHashMap` is optimized for synchronized access in that it is not locked entirely during an operation, so that operations that do not conflict with each other can be performed simultaneously (you might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510632/whats-the-difference-between-concurrenthashmap-and-collections-synchronizedmap)).

  For example, you could make each `Set<Subscriber>` in `Broker.subscribers` a [`ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView.html) (which serves as the `Set` equivalent of a `ConcurrentHashMap`, because there is no class `ConcurrentHashSet`) instead of a regular `HashMap`. This would at least make the `synchronized` block in `Broker.deregister(String, Subscriber)` unnecessary. Making `Broker.subscribers` itself a `ConcurrentHashMap` might also help, but you still have to be careful, for example in the method `Broker.register(String, Subscriber)`, because, without any other synchronization, the first call to `subscribers.containsKey(topic)` might yield `false`, so the `else` block is entered, but before the call `subscribers.put(topic, sub)` is reached, `subscribers` might have been changed and could now already contain a mapping for `topic` which would then be overwritten. There seem to be special methods in the class `ConcurrentHashMap` for such cases (like the `compute` methods), but since this is merely a general suggestion, I won't go into detail about it.
- Your code lacks handling of exceptional cases, for instance, if the methods `deregister(String, Subscriber)` or `sendMessage(String, Map)` are called with a topic that is not contained in the key set of `subscribers`.
- As I already hinted at in a comment, using raw types is a dangerous undertaking. It is not wrong per se, but the risk of bugs is higher because generics provide compile-time type-safety which you are not taking advantage of if you use raw types. I don't know what your code might do with the map, so maybe it won't be a problem, but you might still take a look at [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220192/using-raw-types-in-java-method-signatures) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516878/are-raw-types-always-bad).
- Also note that the `map` that is being passed to `Broker.sendMessage(String, Map)` will be accessed concurrently in `sub.parallelStream().forEach(subscriber -> subscriber.update(map))`, which [might not be desirable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) if the map can be modified by the subscribers.